# How to use decodeIfPresent for all properties of a Codable?

Tags: ios, swift, codable

How do I make a `Codable` class use `decodeIfPresent` for all properties without needing to type out all properties in a custom initializer?

An example:

```
class Book: Codable {
    var name: String = "Default name"
    var pages: Int = 1

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        for key in container.allKeys {
            // What to do here to call decodeIfPresent?
        }
    }
}
```

In essence, I'd like to replicate the automatically created initializer myself, making this one change to how it works.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? A shortcut for decoding the properties, or something else?

Comment: @ItaiFerber Ideally, a generic solution that would allow me to use defaults by default (at least for given classes/structs). Something like `class Book: Codable, DecodableUsingDefaults { ... }`.

Comment: Got it. Yeah, that’s not currently possible; you’ll have to decode each of the properties individually. You can’t meaningfully loop over the available keys this way because you need to set the properties, which isn’t currently possible to generalize in Swift.

Comment: I was just searching for the same feature. What a PITA writing it all by hand is.

Comment: Wow, finding out this is not possible is really a shame. Am I mistaken in thinking this limitation makes it basically impossible to use a protocol (or parent class even) to add save-to-json functionality to a class marked `Codable`? I guess it'd work fine, as long as your class never changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is not possible at this time (Swift 4). This is because Swift does not support setting a property dynamically by name.